# Evaulating the square root of a number greater than 1 upto a certain precision

Tags: c, debugging

This was my code:

```
# include <stdio.h>
float absolute(float x){
  return x>0? x: (-1)*x;
}
float bisect(float a, float b){
  float k = (a+b)*0.5;
   return k;
}
//For n>1
float find(float n, float precision){
  float l=1,m=n;
  float sqrt, k=bisect(l,m);
while(absolute(k*k-n)>precision){
  if(k*k-n>0){
    m=k;
    l=l;
     k=bisect(l,m);
  }
  else if(k*k-n<0)
  {l=k;
  m=m;
    k=bisect(k,m);
  }
 }
  return k;
}
int main(){
  float n, precision;
  scanf("%f %f", &n, &precision);
  printf("%f", find(n, precision));
  return 0;
}
```

Well, it gave me the square root alright, but not up to the precision I specified. For instance, the square root of 3 was given to be 1.734375 and not 1.732050, which is the correct value, in spite of setting the precision equal to 0.001. I spent nearly an hour trying to debug this and now I'm done. Please help me identify where the code went wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: On an unrelated note, to negate a value use the unary negation operator `-`, like in `-x` (instead of multiplying with `-1`). C doesn't really have negative values, only negated positive values.

Comment: You get 1.734375 if you ask for precision 0.01, not 0.001 as you said in your question. Note that your precision is the absolute error you accept in k*k-n, and not the absolute error you accept in sqrt(n) - k. Perhaps that's the source of your confusion?

Comment: Your code gives me `1.731934`

Comment: Please [edit] and show some examples of input and expected output vs. actual output.

Comment: The "correct" value is `1.732` not `1.732050` which isn't accurate either to `0.001` or to `0.000001`, which would be `1.732051`. The number of figures you use should corresponsond/imply the required precision. Moreover, please shove `float` in your 1980's waste bin unless there is a genuine reason why you can't use `double.`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok!

Answer (score 1):

You use precision to compare `k * k` and `n`, while you want the precision for `k` and not for `k * k`.

Your while condition should be instead `while (m - l > precision) { ...`. That is the correct way to make sure that the difference between `k` and the real value is less than `precision`

Comment: Ah yes, with binary search you can bound the absolute error using the bounds you  have. This is obviously simpler than my answer, which bounds the absolute error using only the estimate k.

Comment: @PaulHankin: yes as the *sqrt* is strictly monotonic, the real value has to be inside the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You get 1.734375 if you ask for precision 0.01, not 0.001 as you said in your question. Note that your precision is the absolute error you accept in k*k-n, and not the absolute error you accept in sqrt(n) - k. Perhaps that's the source of your confusion?

If you want to bound the absolute error in the result, you can check that if `k*k < n`, then `(k+precision)*(k+precision) >= n`, or if `k*k>n`, then `(k-precision)*(k-precision) <= n`.

Or alternatively, you can check that `abs(n - k^2 - p^2/4) < pk`, where `p` is the precision. (This is the same as checking that `(k-p/2)^2 < n < (k+p/2)^2`).